# Setting Variable Within Method For Use In Other Method Call

Tags: jquery

I have a button `.js-upload-photos` which when clicked concatenates it's `id` onto a hidden input `#fileupload` and calls .click(). This works correctly. I have another method (I don't know JQuery terminology) below it which calls `.fileupload` on that same element.

My problem is that I can get the dynamically created `id` to concatenate onto my `.click()` method, but I don't know how to use that same `id` for the `.fileupload` call below it.

```
$(function () {
    // open file explorer window
    $(".js-upload-photos").on('click', function(){
        $("#fileupload" + this.id).click();
     });

    // this must be dynamic and match the above .click() element (#fileupload + some id)
    $("#fileupload").fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {  // process response from server
            if (data.result.is_valid) {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried creating a variable outside of the functions and setting the value to `id`, then calling `$("#fileupload" + id_var).fileupload({` but had no luck.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to all the elements and use an `each` loop to initlize the plugin

```
$('.fileupload').each(function() {
  // if need the id use this.id
  $(this).fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function(e, data) { // process response from server
      if (data.result.is_valid) {}
    }
  });
});
```